# Mongoose: Add data to returned result set

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose

Using mongoose in a MEAN environment, I need to add data to a returned mongoose query result. The query returns a list of authors. I want to add a thumbnail field (=calculated path of the thumbnail image) to each author in query result. This is my code (loop code missing for simplicity reasons):

```
var searchQuery = Author.find({ ...foo... }); 
searchQuery.limit(10);
//...

searchQuery.exec(function (err, authors) {
   authors.set('thumbnail', 'test'); //causes error, no effect
   res.json(authors);
});
```

I am aware that mongoose does not return a plain JS/JSON object, hence I need to convert the resultset first to be able to manipulate it. As a matter of fact nothing would work for me and I tried pretty much everything:

```
searchQuery.lean().exec(function (err, authors) { //lean() option makes no difference
```

Converting the result doesn't work either, as I keep getting the "[...] has no method 'xy'" error.

```
var tempresult = authors.toObject(); //--> causes error above
var tempresult = authors.toJSON(); //--> causes error above
```

What else may I have missed?

Comment: What are you trying to do with your data? Are you trying to patch each author by adding a `thumbnail` field to it?

Comment: Yes, that is my intention. I'd therefore need to loop through the result (loop code missing in example above) and apply the change to every dataset of authors.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Once you convert the resulting docs to plain JS objects by using `lean()`, they won't have any of the Mongoose model instance methods available to them like `set`, so you need to directly manipulate them using normal JavaScript object techniques:

```
searchQuery.lean().exec(function (err, authors) {
   authors = authors.map(function(author) {
       author.thumbnail = 'test';
       return author;
   });
   res.json(authors);
});
```

If you want to maintain the results as mongoose docs, then you need to pass `{strict: false}` as a third parameter to [`set`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-set) to allow arbitrary fields to be added:

```
searchQuery.exec(function (err, authors) {
   authors = authors.map(function(author) {
       author.set('thumbnail', 'test', {strict: false});
       return author;
   });
   res.json(authors);
});
```

Comment: Ok, that worked. Thanks so far. But assuming that I'd like to keep the original Mongoose format, how could I manipulate the returned query data (set causes an error as mentioned earlier)?

Comment: lean() is what I've looking for.

Answer (score 3):

you can also just take the returned document in function(res,doc...)
and do:

```
var docForMap = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc));
```

This will give you a new copy that you can work with.